# Python exec with Pip pyinstaller not working on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyinstaller, executable

I have little coding experience but am coding for a research thesis project. I am trying to get my code to be executable. I go into Terminal and change my directory to be where my .py is located. I then type:

pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' *myscript*.py

Things happen and I get a dist folder in the directory as well! However, when I go into the dist and click on *myscript*.exec it quickly opens and closes and I get this on my Terminal window:

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
dyn188-186:~ *user*$ /Users/*user*/Desktop/PATH \ Programs/dist/absolutetest ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

WHAT IS GOING ON?! I thought I was so close to fixing this. The code is in Python 3.9 I believe, but when I type:

python --version
or
python3 --version

into Terminal, it says Python 2.7.16 and 3.9.2 respectively. I have attached my SPEC as well (I have no idea what that is, but I have been reading lots of forums and people attached it as well).

Please ask questions and I will try ANYTHING! Thank you!

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['absolutetest.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/user/Desktop/PATH'],
             binaries=[('/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk', 'tk'), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl', 'tcl')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='absolutetest',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Comment: what error?  it exited clean.

Comment: @RichardBarber my issue is that my program does not stay open at all. In a split second, it executes and closes. I am trying to have the program stay open until my actual code ends. Does that make sense?

Comment: It exited cleanly, without errors, did it not?

Comment: @RichardBarber I am not quite sure what you are getting at. The output that I get is posted above. There is not an error message, but the program does not stay open. I am trying to get it to stay open when I run the .exe file

Comment: Is the program supposed to do anything besides exit clean?

Comment: @RichardBarber Yes! My program opens a tkinter window which is a simple button and text-based game/program. It is a program for a research study I am doing

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue yesterday until I run in command prompt the below code:

```
Pip uninstall typing
```

Thereafter, I run the pyinstaller command in cmd with

```
pyinstaller --onefile myFile.py
```

Where myFile is the name of the file.

Ensure you're running the pyinstaller command in CLI

Be informed that my system OS is Windows 10 pro

Comment: Thanks, @CEO! Do you have any ideas for MacOS?

Comment: @TheLaw did you try the method I suggested? Is it pip install you use on macOS or sudo install? if sudo, then you need to do 
       
      sudo uninstall typing

Comment: for which purpose do you recommend uninstalling `typing` by pip?

Comment: pip uninstalling typing module, not pip installing it. If he tries it, he would tell you the outcome Mr. @RichardBarber

Comment: @CEO I just tried your suggestion with "Pip uninstall typing" and then "pyinstaller --onefile myFile.py" immediately after that. I got the same outcome as before. It executes, but my program never opens :(

Comment: I don't think MacOS user uses pip install or pip uninstall command, get the right command and use it to uninstall typing.

Comment: @CEO this is my screen: pip uninstall typing
WARNING: Skipping typing as it is not installed.